# Gas Dryer Coil Conversion - is this possible?

Tags: dryer, appliances

I have an old Maytag DG410 dryer that operates on natural gas. Recently is started showing signs of a bad solenoid coil on the gas control valve: the flame ignites when the dryer is first started, but after several minutes the gas shuts off, well before the drum has been brought up to temperature. The igniter will then glow as if to start the flame up again, the valve clicks, and the igniter goes out, but no flame is started. This continues for several minutes until the solenoid coil cools down enough to let it briefly operate again.

I went to search for replacement coils, and found these are the older K-series type coils. The price gouging is insane, $150+ for replacements.

I noticed that the newer M-series coils are much cheaper. What I am wondering is if it's possible to retrofit the old valve with the new style coils? They look to be the same, except the newer style uses a single coil on one side instead of 2 smaller coils stacked.

As an alternative, is it possible to replace the valve with the newer style that accepts the M series coils? I know this is a long shot, but having to pick between buying a new dryer and paying outrageously overinflated prices for the parts to fix the one I have is not an attractive choice. I'm hoping there is a third option.

Comment: can you just replace the thermal element

Comment: If the valve uses the same TC or type of input that senesces the heat / flame and has the appropriate output to control the relay or contactor that is energizing the hot surface igniter then yes it can be changed but the specs need to be the same as far as the flame sensor I believe there are 3 different types.

Comment: @knowitall it's a gas dryer. If you are referring to the ignition element, that works fine. The problem is definitely one of the stacked coils that actuate the solenoids on the gas valve.

Comment: And you know it's a bad coil because you've monitored voltage across the coil during a heating cycle and the voltage remains constant but the valve closes anyway? If not, best to confirm that it's not a defect upstream of the coil. You can use insulation displacing wire taps on the coil leads and run temporary wires to your meter. When completed, you can remove the temporary wires but leave the taps in place to safely cover the insulation breaks.

Comment: @MTA I disconnected each coil and checked resistance across them. Two were between 500 and 1000 ohms, but the third was infinite. That struck me as a bit odd, since I was expecting lower resistance caused by a short, not an open circuit. When I hooked it back up it short cycled the burner the same way it did before, then cycled the igniter repeatedly without a flame. I noticed that the suspect coil got pretty hot but the others didn't. I'll try watching the voltage just to be sure, but I'm pretty sure it's the coil.